# could not found method crashlystic() in.fabric

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

```
can anyone tell me the detail steps how to install Fabric for android.i have tried but when i build project it gives me error saying could not find method crashlystics() for argument`here is my app.gradle
```

i given crashlystics at the end.which path should be add to ndkout and ndklibsout in this method.
and where i should see the crash details after installation.i am trying to add Fabric from pluging browse repository.please help me for this.
     buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kekanepc.petpoojaapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.2'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
crashlytics{
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/jniLibs'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/jniLibs'
}`
```